# How JavaScript core methods are implemented?

Tags: javascript

Is there any reference or online site in which I can see how JavaScript core library methods like `push(), join(), split()` etc are implemented like for other language ([glib](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) for C)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It varies by the implementation (within reason, an implementation has to fundamentally follow [the spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/)). You can see all the details of how V8 (Chrome's engine) and SpiderMonkey (Mozilla's) work, they're both open source:

- [V8 Source](https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/Source)
- [SpiderMonkey Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Getting_SpiderMonkey_source_code)

For example, this is how [V8 implements `Array#push`](https://code.google.com/p/v8/codesearch#v8/trunk/src/array.js&q=array%20push&sq=package%3av8&type=cs&l=421) *(the line number in that link will probably rot)*:

```
function ArrayPush() {
  if (IS_NULL_OR_UNDEFINED(this) && !IS_UNDETECTABLE(this)) {
    throw MakeTypeError("called_on_null_or_undefined",
                        ["Array.prototype.push"]);
  }

  var n = TO_UINT32(this.length);
  var m = %_ArgumentsLength();
  for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    this[i+n] = %_Arguments(i);
  }
  this.length = n + m;
  return this.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can learn a great deal about internal logic in the ECMAScript spec, but implementation is dependent on the browser.

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/

Comment: Something that might be an easier read: http://es5.github.io/